# Confused about profiling results from my OpenCL kernel (DSP Window Function)

Tags: profiling, cuda, signal-processing, opencl, nvidia

I completed a Window Function kernel in OpenCL. Basically a window function just applies a set of coefficients over another set of numbers piece by piece (Wikipedia explains it better). I was able to stuff the window coefficient float array in constant cache for most cases.

I expected my results from Compute Prof to show that the host to device and device to host memory transfers would take more than 95% of the processing time. For nearly all of my cases it is only 80% of the processing time. I am writing and reading one 4.2 million float array to and from the board and writing another float array that generally stays well below a million.

Does anything in the kernel look fishy? Any opinions on if it is a problem that should run faster on a GPU than a CPU in the first place(I am still not 100% on this). I am a little stunned as to why my gld_efficiency and gst_efficiency hover between 0.1 and 0.2. I made this kernel with G80 global memory coalescing in mind. My global memory overall throughput seems alright at 40gbs. The kernel is pretty simple and is posted below.

```
__kernel void window(__global float* inputArray, // first frame to ingest starts at 0.  Sized to nFramesToIngest*framesize samples
    __constant float* windowArray, // may already be partly filled
    int windowSize, // size of window frame, in floats
    int primitivesPerDataFrame, //amount of primitives in each frame of inputArray parameter
    int nInFramesThisCall, //each thread solves a frame, so this integer represent how many threads this kernel launches
    int isRealNumbers //0 for complex, non-zero for real 
)
{
int gid = get_global_id(0) + get_global_size(0) * get_global_id(1);

if(gid < nInFramesThisCall) //make sure we don't execute unnecessary threads
{
    if(isRealNumbers)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < primitivesPerDataFrame; i++)
        {
            int inputArrayIndex = (gid*primitivesPerDataFrame)+i;
            inputArray[inputArrayIndex] = inputArray[inputArrayIndex] * windowArray[i%windowSize];
        }
    }
    else //complex
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < primitivesPerDataFrame; i++)
        {
            int inputArrayIndex = (gid*primitivesPerDataFrame)+i;
            inputArray[inputArrayIndex] = inputArray[inputArrayIndex] * windowArray[i%windowSize/2];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many threads (the OpenCL term is work-items, by the way) are you using? You need at least something in the hundreds to load a big GPU efficiently.

You say you want to make use of coalesced memory access, but a load with an offset like

```
int inputArrayIndex = (gid*primitivesPerDataFrame)+i;
```

will not make this possible in most cases. NVidia's G80 has pretty severe restrictions when it comes to coalescing, see the "OpenCL Best Practices Guide" for more information. Basically, work-items from one warp have to access elements of a 64 or 128 byte aligned block in a certain fashion at the same time to make loads and stores happen coalesced.

Or to give you an example: if `primitivesPerDataFrame` is 16, loads and stores of a warp are done at offsets spaced 16 elements apart, making any efficient coalescing impossible.

Comment: I am generally launching 256 threads per block. I believe in my conditional statement, if isRealNumbers == true, then my warp accesses one 128 byte aligned block in InputArray. If isRealNumbers == false, then my warp accesses two 128 byte aligned blocks in InputArray? I feel like the total number of read and write requests should be 1:1 with the total number of read and write transactions. If I am not seeing something, please share, because the profiler doesn't agree with me :)

Comment: Just calculate the offsets for some example where `primitivesPerDataFrame` > 1 and you'll see that accesses are not consecutive, but have a certain stride that quickly gets big enough to make coalescing impossible. Also, you are doing exactly the same global mem accesses for real and complex numbers.

Comment: Sorry if I am being dense, but I do not see how any of my accesses to inputArray are not consecutive. Can you explain how?

Comment: Let's say `primitivesPerDataFrame` is 4 and you're in the first iteration of the first loop. The kernel will access inputArray[0], inputArray[4], inputArray[8] and so on. It gets worse if `primitivesPerDataFrame` gets bigger.

Comment: I am not sure about that, if primitivesPerDataFrame is 4, thread 0 will access inputArray indicies of 0 to 3, and thread 1 will access inputArray indicies of 4-7. Since I am making these contiguous accesses per thread, I feel like they should coalesce (less memory transactions than requests), even by G80 standards. Am I just not understanding something? I don't mean to be dense. The profiler is definitely not agreeing with me :(

Comment: Coalescing means combining *concurrent* accesses of Work-Items from a Half-Warp. Sequential accesses cannot be coalesced.

Comment: I've looked back at the Programming and Best Practices guide and I am now not sure at all if I can have memory coalescing. My stride will usually be in the thousands. Is this is a case where I am just stuck or do you have any recommendations on how I could modify my kernel to make global memory accesses coalesce?

Comment: I feel like I would have to break down my kernel so that instead of a thread solving whole frames, they would only solve one sample of the frame at a time. Would it be worth reducing the operations in kernels and launching more of them so that memory accesses were faster?

Comment: Yes, restructuring your algorithm might be useful (sorry, I'm too lazy to look at how it could be done :)). You should also see if `__local` memory might be useful. Often it can be used to rearrange memory accesses so you can benefit from coalescing.

Comment: I fixed my algorithm. It launches a thread for every multiplication operation. By doing this I can allow a half-warp to index the way a G80 wants it to. Compute Prof now shows my gld and gst efficiency at 1.0 :D Also, according to Compute Prof, my kernels run up to ten times faster now.